# Describing a discrete dynamic system

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, arithmetic

**Model**

There are three types of animals:

- $Y$, young (0-5 years old)
- $A$, adult (5-10 years old)
- $O$, old (10 years old or more)

The initial conditions of the system are $Y_0=2500$, $A_0=1200$, $O_0=500$.

The probability that:

- an young animal turns into an adult one is $0.68$
- an adult animal turns into an old one is $0.30$
- an old animal dies is $0.8$

The adult and old animals produce together $90$ offspring per $100$ animals.

**Problems**

1. Using the information above describe the system with difference equations.

$Y(t)=$

$A(t)=$

$O(t)=$

where $t$ is a time constant. $t=0$ is 2006. Each $t$ increment by $1$ corresponds to $5$ years in real world.

2. Find an $\frac{offsprings}{animals}$ ratio for which the becomes stable

---

That's what I've tried, however it doesn't seem to describe this system well:

1.
$$Y(t)=0.9(O(t-1)+A(t-1))$$
        $$A(t)=0.68Y(t-1)$$
        $$O(t)=0.3A(t-1)+0.2O(t-1)$$

Any ideas and hints are appreciated, feel free to ask questions in the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:
\begin{align*}
Y_{n+1}&=0.90O_n+0.90A_n\\
A_{n+1}&=0.68Y_n\\
O_{n+1}&=0.30A_n-0.80O_n
\end{align*}